# Is there any Timer () or Clock () function in AndroidViewClient?

Tags: timer, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I'm using Androidviewclient for black-box testing of a GUI and I need to record the response time of a button; for example I need to know how long it takes for the next screen to appear from the time I click a "Next" button On a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `profileStart()` and `profileEnd()` in `common.py` (https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/common.py). They will provide you the means of profiling those cases.